# Allow all users to change computer name

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, group-policy, gpedit

I have to enable the normal users on Windows 10 devices to change the computer name (host name) using command prompt or powershell. But seems like the normal users are not allowed to change the name. I have tried following commands which works fine with administrator but not with normal users:

Command prompt:

```
WMIC computersystem where caption='CurrentName' rename 'NewName'
```

Powershell:

```
Rename-Computer -NewName "NewName"
```

Is there a way to allow normal users to rename computer through GPEdit? Or any other way without making the user an admin?

Comment: No; There isn’t;

Comment: Why do you need regular users to change the computer name?

Comment: there are ways to let users trigger a higher-privilege call. the ones i see most often are to set up Jenkins or a web page - and let that use an special account to run the "admin-required" command.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey - Sounds extremely insecure way of allowing a normal user to perform an function that should be done by an Administrator.  If your going to do that just give the user an Administrator account at least that way it can be audited.

Comment: @Ramhound - it can be very insecure. [*grin*] however, it can be reasonably secure in that you can limit what commands are allowed and can keep track of who does what. allowing a system rename might be OK. _i agree that entering a ticket to request the rename is safer, tho._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't comment on whether allowing everyone to rename the computer is a good idea, but it is possible to allow just one privileged operation by granting permission to start a scheduled task that runs as `SYSTEM`. Extra info can be passed to the privileged task in a file that's writable by anyone; I'll use `compname.txt` in `C:\Users\Public\Documents`.

In an administrative PowerShell prompt, create a scheduled task that runs as `SYSTEM` and invokes PowerShell to set the computer name to whatever's in that text file:

```
New-ScheduledTask -Action (New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'powershell' -Argument '-command Rename-Computer (gc "C:\Users\Public\Documents\compname.txt")') -Principal (New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' -LogonType ServiceAccount) | Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'RenameComputer'
```

Unfortunately the PowerShell cmdlets for Task Scheduler don't support adjusting the security descriptor, so we'll have to use the COM scripting API instead. To reconfigure the task to additionally grant read (`FR`) and execute (`FX`) permissions to the Users group (`BU`):

```text
$ts = New-Object -ComObject 'Schedule.Service'
$ts.Connect('localhost')
$ts.GetFolder('\').GetTask('RenameComputer').SetSecurityDescriptor('D:(A;ID;0x1f019f;;;BA)(A;ID;0x1f019f;;;SY)(A;ID;FA;;;BA)(A;;FR;;;SY)(A;;FRFX;;;BU)', 0)
```

Non-administrators will then be able to see and run the scheduled task, but not alter it. They can change the computer name by writing to that text file and starting the task, e.g. with this PowerShell:

```
'NEWNAME' | Out-File 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\compname.txt'
Start-ScheduledTask 'RenameComputer'
```

If you need to keep track of who renamed the computer, you could enable auditing on the folder containing the text file.

Answer (score 1):

To change the computer name, local administrator privilege is required and there is no independent permission can be assigned.

You can add the normal user account in the local Administrators Group. However, if you do not want to give the local administrator privilege, you may need to change the computer name for your users.