# How to run a PowerShell script with elevated Access using Task Scheduler

Tags: windows-10, powershell, script, scheduled-tasks

I have a PowerShell script that I want to use to close applications running in a different users session.  The script works when ran as an administrator, however I  don't want to give the users admin rights just to close the application running in the other users session.  I created a Task in Task Scheduler that should allow the task to run as an administrator using stored credentials.  See task below:

[image: Scheduled Task]

I then created a short to link to that scheduled task and dropped it on the public desktop.  Here is the path for that:

> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
> -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\SMS_Killer.ps1

I have put in an Execution Bypass however that doesn't seem to work unless an administrator is logged in.

Here is the code that is being ran by the task execution:

```
Get-Process | Where {$_.ProcessName -eq "firefox"} | Stop-Process

Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

And here is the error I get when I run it as a non administrator:

```
Stop-Process : Cannot stop process "firefox (3328)" because of the following error: Access is denied
At C:\SMS_Killer.ps1:5 char:54
+ Get-Process | Where {$_.ProcessName -eq "firefox"} | Stop-Process
+                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (System.Diagnostics.Process (firefox):Process) [Stop-Process], ProcessComman
   dException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStopProcess,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StopProcessCommand
```

Any help would be much appreciated not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: I'm not certain that I understand correctly, but if you are trying to allow everyone to run a specific privileged scheduled task, I believe you need to adjust the task's ACL like in [my answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1612231/380318).

Comment: @BenN not sure I fully understand how that will help me here.  Are you suggesting that I would have to use PowerShell to create the Scheduled Task so that it will run as system instead of administrator?

Comment: My understanding of the problem was that you want everyone to be able to run a specific bit of code as administrator, but your scheduled task that you set up to run the code is not actually running when non-administrators try to use it. My answer creates and changes the configuration of a task so that it can actually be started by non-administrators. I don't think SYSTEM vs. administrator should make a difference; it's just easier to create tasks that run as SYSTEM.

Comment: @TylerColeman I'm curious if you got a chance to look over and test my answer? If so, what you think, etc. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If it is safe for the process to be killed if it is running while any user account is logging in or reconnecting to a disconnected session, then let `SYSTEM` run the task triggering it a little differently with events instead.

Doing it this way will prevent the need for any user account to have the permission to execute the task. This executes it each time it is trigged per specific conditional events.

---

## Configure the scheduled task

1. Schedule the task to run as `SYSTEM`

[image]

2. Set the three triggers as such:

   - `At log on` of `Any user`
   - `On connection to user session` for `Any user` when `Connection from remote computer`
   - `On connection to user session` for `Any user` when `Connection from local computer`

> **Note:** Set each of these three triggers with a `Delay task for` value of `10 seconds`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the latest versions of Windows 10, doing `schtasks /run` now requires
administrator permissions.
It is no longer possible to use this trick for a non-admin user.
Microsoft has closed the loophole in Windows
by which a non-admin user could launch an admin task via the Task Scheduler.

You are probably looking for a way to make this method work again,
as it has worked for so many years, but this is no longer possible.

An alternative solution that still works is the utility
[RunAsSpc](https://robotronic.de/runasspcen.html),
free for private use, described as:

> Run application as another user or start program as administrator from a limited account like the command `runas`, but without to enter login information on each start.